# Testing a mixin function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I have a mixin function which is as follows -

```
function mixin(receiver, supplier) {
    for (var property in supplier) {
        if (supplier.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            receiver[property] = supplier[property];
        }
    }
}
```

To test this function, I am using the `ok` method of Qunit -

```
test('Mixin Test Runner', function () {
    // using OK method
    ok(function () {
        var receiver = {
            name: 'Abul Moksud',
            age: '60'
        };

        var supplier = {
            hands: 2
        };

        mixin(receiver, supplier);

        return receiver.hasOwnProperty('hands') && (receiver.hands === 2);
    }(), "Abul Moksud now has two hands");
});
```

I am an absolute beginner in both unit testing and QUnit. Is my approach OK here, or is there any better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, but can be simplified. `ok` method usually gets an expression rather than a in-place function that is immediately evaluated.

Here is how I would write this test:

```
test('Mixin Test Runner', function () {
    var receiver = {
        name: 'Abul Moksud',
        age: '60'
    };

    var supplier = {
        hands: 2
    };

    mixin(receiver, supplier);

    //Assertion phase
    ok(receiver.hasOwnProperty("hands"), "hands property is defined on reciever");
    equal(receiver.hands, 2, "Abul Moksud now has two hands");
});
```